# Laravel - Cannot access routes in MAMP

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

I'm developed a project in Laravel and i have work with artisan but now i need to pass the project to MAMP.

So, i copy the project folder and put it in htdocs folder.

For exemple i have a route named /app/groups but now mamp doesn't recognizes this route neither access to css and js files.

How can i solve this problem?

For exemple i'm doing this:

```
<a href="/app/groups/" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect color">
                  Entrar
                </a>
```

And i works with artisan but now with mamp not.

Thank you

Comment: What is the url you're using to access your app?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/arquivo/public/ and it goes to welcome view but when i click in the button above  give me a not found error. @RossWilson

Comment: I think that i have to put arquivo/public in all path but should not right? @RossWilson

Comment: Are you on windows or mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below, mybe this help to test your routes, I think you moved it to subfolders.

`<a href="{{url('/')}}/app/groups/" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect color"> Entrar</a>`

Hope this helps .

Comment: Just an FYI, when you're using the `url()` helper method you can pass the path you want to go to in to the function i.e. `url('app/groups')` (the `/` will be added for you as well).